# Does JavaScript have any functionality for building URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index view of cards (e.g. playing cards) laid out in a BootStrap grid. Each card is in a div, and I have a jQuery `click` handler for each div, to open a details page for any card (card div) that is clicked. So the redirect from the index to detail view is all accomplished using this (rather smelly) JavaScript:

```
var showDetail = function (index) {
    const newUrl = "@($"http://{Model.HostName}{Url.Action("Details", "Card")}/")" + index;
    window.location = newUrl;
};
```

I don't like to depend on the Razor code nugget to give me the hostname and the url's path. Does JavaScript have any functionality that I can use to achieve the same as the above dodgy code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Comment: @gurvinder372 The `URL` ctor requires a `url` parameter, and if its value is a relative URL, it also requires a `base` URL parameter. To provide that base url, I will still need to use `$"http://{Model.HostName}`, where I don't want any hard coding. How do I adjust for SSL?

Comment: @Satpal I don't have a care in the world if IE doesn't support it. I don't support IE. Edge supports it though, and IE will probably be deprecated by the time this project is finished.

Comment: _IE will probably be deprecated_, Thats the best thing I header today. You can create an anchor on the fly and read its property `$('<a>', { "href" : relativeUrl}).prop('href ')`

Comment: All the URL API seems to do is concatenate the relative and base URLs, and probably escape them. So its only value for me is the escaping, if done.

Comment: @Satpal Yes, sorry, I misread your first comment about the anchor.

Comment: @Satpal That's good enough for me, even if I'm still stuck with Razor to get the relative url. Why not answer the question with your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create create an anchor on the fly and read its `href` property.

```js
console.log($('<a>', {
  "href": '/test/for/relative/url'
}).prop('href'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And, Also [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) can be used.

Comment: Thanks. I really learned something fairly esoteric about jQuery today.

Comment: @ProfK, you will get the same result using vanilla js. I was being lazy

Comment: Why use vanilla when you have the Swiss chocolate of jQuery?